# QuickBlox' QB.chat.addlistener only working sporadically, can't tell why or what triggers it

Tags: javascript, quickblox

Having difficulty with this working at seemingly random times. When I go into the chat page, the controller activates, and immediately after that the before addlistener and after addlistener console.logs fire, and then sometimes when I send a message, it is received with a console printout of the package contents, but more often it isn't. And sometimes, it is printed on the console of the computer that fires off the send message instead of the receiving end.

At the very least, though, whenever I send a message, even if I don't get a console printout of the package, I get a corresponding [QBChat RECV]:, [object Object] - hit the button ten times, get ten QBChat RECVs.

```js
.controller('ChatCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, $rootScope, $ionicLoading) {
  console.log("Inside ChatCtrl");
  
  QB.createSession(function(err,result){
    console.log('Session create callback', err, result);
    console.log('Session create callback' + JSON.stringify(result));
  });

  $scope.settings = {};
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.error = {};

  $scope.signInClick = function() {
    console.log('Login was clicked');
     
      $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
          content: 'Logging in',
          animation: 'fade-in',
          showBackdrop: true,
          maxWidth: 200,
          showDelay: 0
      });
      var params = {'login': ($scope.user.username), 'password': ($scope.user.password)}
      console.log("params... " + JSON.stringify(params));

      QB.users.create(params, function(err, user){
        if (user) {
          console.log("successful user.create... " + JSON.stringify(user));
          var jid = user.id + "-#####" + "@chat.quickblox.com";
          var chatparams = {'jid': jid, 'password': ($scope.user.password)};
          QB.chat.connect(chatparams, function(err, roster) {
            console.log("err from qb.chat.connect... " + JSON.stringify(err));
            console.log("roster from qb.chat.connect .... " + JSON.stringify(roster));
          });
        } else  {
          if (err.message == "Unprocessable Entity"){
            QB.login(params, function(err, user){
              if (user) {
                console.log("Logged into QB with " + JSON.stringify(user));
                var jid = user.id + "-#####" + "@chat.quickblox.com";
                console.log(user.login + "'s jid is......" + jid);
                var chatparams = {'jid': jid, 'password': ($scope.user.password)};
                QB.chat.connect(chatparams, function(err, roster) {
                  console.log("stringifying the roster... " + JSON.stringify(roster));
                });
              } 
              else  {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
      
      // var chatparams = {'jid': jid, 'password': ($scope.user.password)};
      // console.log("the jid is......" + jid);
      // console.log("chatparams is ......" + JSON.stringify)

      Parse.User.logIn(($scope.user.username) , $scope.user.password, {
          success: function(_user) {
              console.log('Login Success');
              console.log('user = ' + _user.attributes.username);
              console.log('email = ' + _user.attributes.email);
              $ionicLoading.hide();
              $rootScope.user = _user;
              $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
              // $state.go('tab.home');
          },
          error: function(user, err) {
              $ionicLoading.hide();
              // The login failed. Check error to see why.
              if (err.code === 101) {
                  $scope.error.message = 'Invalid login credentials';
              } else {
                  $scope.error.message = 'An unexpected error has ' +
                      'occurred, please try again.';
              }
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      });
    // $state.go('tab.profile');
  };


  $scope.sendMessageClick = function() {

    var user = $rootScope.user.attributes.username;
    console.log("user = " + user);
    console.log('sendMessageclick');
    
    var countchew = "3354163-#####@chat.quickblox.com"; //countchew
    var starshipenterprise = "3354099-#####@chat.quickblox.com"; //starshipenterprise
    QB.chat.roster.get(function(roster) {
      console.log("roster.get before if block  " + JSON.stringify(roster));
    });
    if (user == "countchew"){
      QB.chat.roster.confirm(starshipenterprise, function(){
        console.log("roster.confirm called");
      });
      QB.chat.roster.add(starshipenterprise, function() {
        console.log("roster.add called");
      });
      QB.chat.send(starshipenterprise, {
          type: 'chat',
          name: 'testmessage',
          body: 'Hello world!',
          extension: {save_to_history: 1}
      });
      // QB.chat.roster.remove(starshipenterprise, function() {
      //   console.log("roster.remove starship ... ");
      // });
      QB.chat.roster.get(function(roster) {
        console.log("end of if statement  " + JSON.stringify(roster));
      });
    } else if (user == "starshipenterprise"){
      QB.chat.roster.confirm(countchew, function() {
        console.log("roster.confirm called");
      });
      QB.chat.roster.add(countchew, function() {
        console.log("roster.add called");
      });
      QB.chat.send(countchew, {
          type: 'chat',
          body: 'Hello world!'
      });
    }

  };
  
  console.log("before addlistener");
  QB.chat.addListener({from: '3354163-#####@chat.quickblox.com'}, function() {
    QB.chat.onMessageListener = function(userId, message) {
      console.log('userId ..... ' + userId);
      console.log('message .... ' + JSON.stringify(message));
    };
  });
  console.log("after addlistener");


  var chatparams1 = {from: '3354099-#####@chat.quickblox.com'};
  console.log("before addlistener");
  QB.chat.addListener(chatparams1, function() {
    QB.chat.onMessageListener = function(userId, message) {
      console.log('userId ..... ' + userId);
      console.log('message .... ' + JSON.stringify(message));
    };
  });
  console.log("after addlistener");

  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great! Figured it out.

You need to pay attention to the XML packages that it sends. What was happening is that somehow, when it first got up and running and was working well with the corresponding QB chat addresses for the account, after that, at some point it started appending a string of numbers-quickblox-numbers (35896363-quickblox-20942 or whatever) in the 'from' field for the address, which is what I had my listener listening to. The confusing thing is that this worked sporadically.

You can't hardcode the addresses because this string of numbers at the end changes with every login.

Instead, it is working for the time being to just listen for messages with the parameters {name: 'message', type: 'chat'}.

Answer (score 1):

A better way could be:

```
QB.chat.addListener( {name: 'message'}, function() {
            $log.debug(" main: QB listener by filter was triggered");
});
```

Or just:

```
QB.chat.onMessageListener = showMessage;
```

That code has to be run **once** (at first init, on system loading).

- onMessageListener will be triggered every time.
- addListener will be triggered only if msg is with name'message'. (filter of listener)

Then you need a function with such a signature:

```
function showMessage(userId, msg) {
    console.log('main.showMessage:: on message', msg)
}
```